# Javascript and tipped arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a web page with JavaScript and HTML. I am use jQuery and I must highlight a selected dates. I have that array:

```
var events = [ 
{ Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("02/13/2013"), dir: "http://www.google.es" }, 
{ Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("02/25/2013") }, 
{ Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2013") }
];
```

My question is, how I can add an element in that array? I tried a lot of things and I dont know how. And another question, what is the name of that kind of array?

EDIT:

I see one thing. If a add a date like "01/05/2013", the array is like that:

```
Wed Feb 13 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de verano romance)
Mon Feb 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de verano romance)    
Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de verano romance)
Sat Jan 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de verano romance)
```

And prints the date in the datepicker. But if I add a date like "05/05/2013" then:

```
Wed Feb 13 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de verano romance)
Mon Feb 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de verano romance)
Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de verano romance)
Sun May 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

You will see? The new date its diffent of the other. And in this case, the date are not highlited in the datepicker. Anyone knows why?

Comment: That's a perfectly normal array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: What's a tipped array?

Comment: It's an **Array of Object literals**.

Comment: @Elseine, you're asking why _1._ `"05/05/2013"` is `GMT+0200` when the others are `GMT+0100`, and _2._ why `"01/05/2013"` is `Jan` when you expected `May`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no a true name for that array, it's just an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)s.
To append a new `Object` you have to do this:

```
events.push({Title: '...', ...}); //define the object to be appended
```

To define a new Date object you should use this constructor:

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
//in this case it will be(month goes from 0 to 11)
new Date(2013, 4, 5); //this will be the 5th of May(which is 4)
```

There are a lot of methods for the `Date Object`, you just have to choose which one is the best for your purposes!

Reference to the [Date Object - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: I put that:
events.push({Title: "Metting",Date: new Date("05/05/2013")});
and now show it.

Comment: What do you mean with "show"? Display in HTML page?

Comment: Then of that, I have a function that print a datepicker. The 3 dates that are initially on the array are pritned, but the four that I add no.

Comment: I edited with all the new information.